# schemas.enable=false config not applied to connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongo-connector

I am using mongokafka sink connector from kafka to mongo and connector jar is mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0-all.jar.I have added mongodb-driver-core-4.5.0.jar also in plugins path of connect cluster.
I am using strimzi kafka and connect. In kafka I could successful send message but in connector I could see error.

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '
     {"name": "mongo-sink",
      "config": {
         "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
         "connection.uri":"mongodb://mongoservice:27017/?replicaSet=rs0",
         "database":"quickstart",
         "collection":"topicData",
         "topics":"q4.s4"
        }
     }
     ' \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors -w "\n"
```

sample Message:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "hello"}
```

Error in connector:

`{"name":"mongo-sink","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"localhost:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"localhost:8083","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:540)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t... 13 more\n"}],"type":"sink"}`

I tried to set "schemas.enable":"false" in connector config but still same issue.

Do I need to start any other service like schema registry ? currently I am using strimzi kafka and connect with mongodbv5.0.3 and mongo-kafka-connect-1.7.0-all.jar ,mongodb-driver-core-4.5.0.jar.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to set "schemas.enable":"false" in connector config but still same issue.

The error is for the **converter**, not the connector. That config is not a valid Mongo Connector property.

Since you are only interested in the value of the record, then set

`"value.converter.schemas.enable" : "false"`

> Do I need to start any other service like schema registry

If you were using `kafka-avro-console-producer`, or similar tool to send the record, then yes.

> currently I am using strimzi kafka

You can use `KafkaConnector` CRD rather than invoke the Connect API directly.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be direct answer, but may be helpful.
In my case "Confluent S3 Sink Connector", config in request parameter is cached in topic's config. So, I cannot overwrite config value without deleting that topic. This is not written in Confluent Docs...